# TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have some long winded code here with an issue when I am attempting to join (or merge/concat) two datasets together, I get this `TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'`

The two datasets both come from resampling the same initial starting dataset. The `master_hrs` df is a resampling process using the a change point algorithm Python package called rupters. (`pip install ruptures` to run code). `daily_summary` df is just using Pandas to resample daily mean & sum values. But I get the error when I attempt to combine the datasets together. Would anyone have any tips to try?

Making up some fake data generates the same error as my real world dataset. I think the issue I have is I am trying to compare datime to numpy some how... Any tips greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
import ruptures as rpt
import calendar

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(11)

rows,cols = 50000,2
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='H') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Temperature','Value'], index=tidx)

def changPointDf(df):
    arr = np.array(df.Value)
    #Define Binary Segmentation search method
    model = "l2"  
    algo = rpt.Binseg(model=model).fit(arr)
    my_bkps = algo.predict(n_bkps=5)
    # getting the timestamps of the change points
    bkps_timestamps = df.iloc[[0] + my_bkps[:-1] +[-1]].index
    # computing the durations between change points
    durations = (bkps_timestamps[1:] - bkps_timestamps[:-1])
    #hours calc
    d = durations.seconds/60/60
    d_f = pd.DataFrame(d)
    df2 = d_f.T
    return df2


master_hrs = pd.DataFrame()


for idx, days in df.groupby(df.index.date):
    changPoint_df = changPointDf(days)
    values = changPoint_df.values.tolist()
    master_hrs=master_hrs.append(values)


master_hrs.columns = ['overnight_AM_hrs', 'moring_startup_hrs', 'moring_ramp_hrs', 'high_load_hrs', 'evening_shoulder_hrs']

daily_summary = pd.DataFrame()

daily_summary['Temperature'] = df['Temperature'].resample('D').mean()
daily_summary['Value'] = df['Value'].resample('D').sum()

final_df = daily_summary.join(master_hrs)
```

Comment: the way you build `master_hrs` does not include datetimeindex because you `append` only the values, so an array without index, from the `changPoint_df`. so the join can't work with `daily_summary` that has a datetimeindex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the indexes themselves - `master_hrs` was int64 whereas `daily_summary` was datetime. Include this before joining the two dataframes together:

```py
master_hrs.index = pd.to_datetime(master_hrs.index)
```

Just for clarity, here's my output of `final_df`:

```py
            Temperature      Value  ...  high_load_hrs  evening_shoulder_hrs
2019-01-01     0.417517  12.154527  ...            NaN                   NaN
2019-01-02     0.521131  13.811842  ...            NaN                   NaN
2019-01-03     0.583205  12.568966  ...            NaN                   NaN
2019-01-04     0.448225  14.036136  ...            NaN                   NaN
2019-01-05     0.542870  10.738192  ...            NaN                   NaN
                ...        ...  ...            ...                   ...
2024-09-10     0.470421  13.775528  ...            NaN                   NaN
2024-09-11     0.384672  10.473930  ...            NaN                   NaN
2024-09-12     0.527284  14.000231  ...            NaN                   NaN
2024-09-13     0.555646  11.460867  ...            NaN                   NaN
2024-09-14     0.426003   3.763975  ...            NaN                   NaN

[2084 rows x 7 columns]
```

Hopefully this gets you what you need.

Comment: Hi Brandon, as shown in your answer the values are null for the columns on the left hand side are null. Would you recommend a merge or concat so that everything is lined up on the index timestampt..?